# Icons/background/descriptions not aligned in weather app (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript

It's sunny and daytime at my location, and the way I've set up the code it should show a blue background and sunny icon, but it's showing the background and icon for "night-clear". I've tried messing about with the backgroundID section to make it work but there's still something wrong. Here's the piece of the code:

```
var location = weatherData.name,
            condition = weatherData.weather[0].description, 
            id = weatherData.weather[0].id,
            countryShort = weatherData.sys.country,
            iconClass,
            bgIndex,
            backgroundId = [299, 499, 599, 699, 799, 800, 904],
            backgroundIcon = ['thunderstorm', 'sprinkle', 'rain', 'snow', 'fog', 'night-clear', 'cloudy', 'hot'],
            backgroundImg = [
                'https://www.dropbox.com/s/7cypfufwhoemt9v/thunder.png?dl=1',
                'https://www.dropbox.com/s/t53xhepev02tfzs/rain%20fog.png?dl=1',
                'https://www.dropbox.com/s/t53xhepev02tfzs/rain%20fog.png?dl=1',
                'https://www.dropbox.com/s/6l75dkzo3uugfli/snow.png?dl=1',
                'https://www.dropbox.com/s/t53xhepev02tfzs/rain%20fog.png?dl=1',
                'https://www.dropbox.com/s/w9scp9a0quffttx/night%20clear.png?dl=1',
                'https://www.dropbox.com/s/t53xhepev02tfzs/rain%20fog.png?dl=1'
              'https://www.dropbox.com/s/dzerxsrq4mz9z6l/day%20clear.png?dl=1'

            ];
```

And here's the full code: http://codepen.io/l-emi/pen/OXBwxL

Here's what I'm seeing:

[image]

Comment: Are you sure about the IDs in `backgroundId` array? They dont appear in the API docs http://www.openweathermap.org/weather-conditions#Weather-Condition-Codes-2 | Also, why are you pushing the ID got in the request into that array? Aren't you trying to match the request's ID with one in that array?

Comment: I changed the IDs...though I'm not sure if it's correct because I'm using [these icons](http://erikflowers.github.io/weather-icons/) instead. I'm afraid I don't understand the last part completely!